# Redirection giving Control M in logs

Tags: linux, bash, shell, ssh, sh

I am redirecting a script to logs

test.sh >> mylog

test.sh has

```
spawn scp -o stricthostkeychecking=no /root/.ssh/id_rsa.pub
root@$IP:/root/.ssh/authorized_keys
```

I am getting logs as

```
spawn scp -o stricthostkeychecking=no /root/.ssh/id_rsa.pub root@IP:/root/.ssh/authorized_keys^M
Warning: Permanently added 'IP' (RSA) to the list of known hosts.^M^M
root@10.112.75.21's password: ^M
^Mid_rsa.pub                                      0%    0     0.0KB/s   --:-- ETA^Mid_rsa.pub                                    100%  405     0.4KB/s   00:00    ^M
Host key verification failed.^M
Host key verification failed.^M
```

What is the reason that might be adding Control-M to my logs ? Am I doing anything wrong while redirection.

Thanks you

PS: All my systems are unix based systems

Comment: I can't be the only one wondering where that "spawn" command comes from.

Answer (score 0):

It is normal. If you have any colored character shown, any application changing the title or working in "full-screen" mode, you will get even worse ANSI sequences (escapes, ...).
You may use `col` or `recode` to manipulate such an output.

This may be because of the option -t of ssh.